# Metaphone 3 information

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, search, match, metaphone

Does anyone know where code can be found for Metaphone 3 matching for T-SQL or at least something that describes in detail the difference between Double Metaphone and Metaphone 3?  I have been working on evaluating different matching algorithms in SQL Server and would like to see how this algorithm performs but can find very little information on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metaphone-3 is a commercial product from http://www.amorphics.com/.

Answer (score 0):

There's a Java implementation of Metaphone3 in the source code of OpenRefine, which is a BSD-Licensed former Google product: [Metaphone3.java](https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/blob/9f7d5b878628c40d68a445b751fd50140d922e7d/main/src/com/google/refine/clustering/binning/Metaphone3.java).